Run shell script in Automator with privileges
I'm trying to run a shell script in an Automator folder action that runs with privileges strong enough to delete files within that folder.
The folder action contains only a Run Shell Script action with the following content:
cd /Users/bob/Downloads/IncomingFiles;
find ./ -type d -name 'fonts' -exec rm -rf {} +;
find ./ -type d -name 'reports' -exec rm -rf {} +;
find ./ -type d -name 'invoices' -exec rm -rf {} +;

If I run the script within Automator it works perfectly, when run as a folder action, it doesn't work. I'm guessing it's a privileges issue, how can I work around it?term
